# Create strings on the fly using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a number of strings based on one long string that i'm passing.

Basically this is an example of my long string

```
StrMain = AL123456 - PR123456 - RD123456 - LO123456
```

So in this case I want to create 4 separate strings.

```
Str1 = AL123456
Str2 = PR123456
Str3 = RD123456
Str4 = LO123456
```

But there isn't always that many or there may be more so I need to count how many `-` there are and with that then create the amount strings needed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we have:

```
var input = "AL123456 - PR123456 - RD123456 - LO123456"
```

then

```
input.Split('-');
```

will return

```
{ "AL123456 ", " PR123456 ", " RD123456 ", " LO123456" }
```

i.e. with leading and trailing spaces.

So you need trim each:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<string> result = input.Split('-').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

(`Select()` requires .NET 3.5+)

---

Or just split by `" - "`:

```
var result = input.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or using VB.NET syntax:

```
Dim result As String() = input.Split({ " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

---

I guess VB.NET has next syntax for for-each:

```
For Each str As String In result
    Response.Write(str) ' or use str in other context '
End For
```

Comment: surely this creates one string? I need four separate strings

Comment: @Jamie: This will return an array of 4 strings. So use `ForEach` to iterate the resulting array and write an item

Comment: How do I do the `ForEach` to write a new string? And then show those strings in different labels?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function:

```
Dim tokens As String() = "AL123456 - PR123456 - RD123456 - LO123456".Split("-"C)
```

or if you want to use a string as separator:

```
Dim tokens As String() = "AL123456 - PR123456 - RD123456 - LO123456".Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Might want to split on `" - "` instead, since there are spaces in the string as well.

Comment: @Bevin, did you click on the link I provided? Apparently not.

Comment: All im getting is `System.String[]` on my page when i use your code?

Comment: That's because the Split function returns an array. You need to loop through the elements of this array and format the output depending on your needs.

Comment: In my `For Each` how can I create a string based on the output. I just want to create a label with the data from that string in and then display it on the page

Answer (score 1):

Use the [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function

This is the use i recommend is below, you can adapt it by either:

- adding more separators (add strings to the separator array like this: `New String() {" - ", " _ "}` )
- removing empty entries (not necessary, but usually useful)

> ```
> Dim MyString As String = "value1 - value2 - value3 -  - value4"
> Dim results As String() = MyString.Split(New String() {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
> ' you get an array with 4 entries containing each individual string
> ```

---